# replacing cell values in dataframe for specific variables

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, replace

I have thousands of rows in each column. I need to find specific values in column `A` based on the value of column `B`, and replace column `A` with a new value if it is greater than a specific value.

For example, if column `B = 1` and the values in column `A > 2`, then I want to replace all the values in column `A > 2` equal to `2` when column `B = 1`.

I've tried this code:

```
if(dt$B=='1'){

  dt <- dt %>% mutate(A = ifelse(A > 2, 2, A))

}
```

But this does not work. I've tried some other methods as well, but nothing I do works. Please let me know if you can help with this! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have a `&` option within `ifelse` for the `test` condition

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- dt %>%
              mutate(A = ifelse(A > 2 & B == 1, 2, A))
```